# Gap above header breaking page in Chrome/Opera

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a gap appearing above the header of my page in Chrome and Opera which is breaking the navigation and other parts of the page. Please see [here](http://samnorris.co.nz/tesla/).

I had this exact same problem before rebuilding my site but can't for the life of me remember now what the problem was or what I did to fix it... hopefully it is not something too stupidly simple and obvious, and allow me to apologize in advance if it is, but I'm feeling a bit too mentally drained to even think straight enough to figure it out at the moment, despite my best efforts.

I suspect it may be somehow related to the simple PHP script which randomly loads either index1.html or index2.html from the root directory, since if you go to either URL directly (ie. http://samnorris.co.nz/tesla/index2.html) the problem is no longer apparent... I'm not sure if some kind of invisible error is being spit out or something which is breaking the page?

This is the PHP script which is contained in an index.php in the root dir

```
<?php
$randNumber = mt_rand(1,3);
if ( $randNumber == 1 )
{
    include 'index1.html';
}
else
{
    include 'index2.html';
}
?>
```

I have checked the Web Inspector tools in Chrome but am not overly familiar enough to know how to interpret it properly, there seems to be one small error relating to part of a script in siriwave.js - but I don't think it is related...

I'm at a bit of a loss, so any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: it happens some times when you use HTML 5 tags like <nav> <header> <footer> with margins and padding . it renders different in different browsers

Comment: True. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the header since I tried removing that and the problem persists, so maybe something to do with the <nav> tag? Shouldn't HTML resets theoretically take care of stuff like that though? I'm using both normalize.css and another basic HTML reset...

Answer (score 1):

The response of http://samnorris.co.nz/tesla/index2.html and http://samnorris.co.nz/tesla/ are  not the same.

http://samnorris.co.nz/tesla/index2.html
[image]

http://samnorris.co.nz/tesla/
[image]

Due to the presence of `<U+FEFF><U+FEFF>`
The whole **parsed** `HTML` is getting malformed for http://samnorris.co.nz/tesla/

The tags specified within `head` are appearing within `body`.
[image]

What is injecting these `<U+FEFF><U+FEFF>`extra characters?

Comment: Yeah, I assume thats because what's happening is that it is set up to load an index.php which just contains a very basic randomization PHP script which then loads either index1.html or index2.html.... I have no idea why this would cause the head content to end up in the body of the loaded page though! weeeeeird. I have also tried setting it up as an index.html with the PHP file just as a PHP include in the page, which works as far as the script goes... but again the same problem in Chrome and Opera. Wish I could remember how I fixed it last time... :(

Comment: Incidentally, what exactly is <U+FEFF><U+FEFF> - any do you happen to have any idea how I might go about preventing the issue from occurring? edit: oops, just realized you're as mystified about it as I am...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, definitely solved it this time. Seems this was the issue: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/weird-characters-inserted-before-doctype

something to do with incorrectly formatted UTF encoding in the php file... very weird indeed.

Comment: That was listed in the W3C validator... glad you figuired it out!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsamnorris.co.nz%2Ftesla%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

`<head></head>` element is empty. Your `meta`,`link`, tags are below your head.

Comment: If you check index1.html in the validator (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsamnorris.co.nz%2Ftesla%2Findex1.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) there is only 1 minor error.... it is only when loading from the root URL that the page is broken (presumably because of how this PHP script I'm using is set up...)

Comment: Hmm, anyone got any other suggestions...? :(